# Python ElementTree problems

Tags: python, xml, ironpython, elementtree

Sry if i am wrong here with that question.. I hope there is no problem exactly like this. And also sry, if i broke any rule in this forum.. Its my first post and question. Thank you for all answers

I am creating a XML-File with python in Revit Dynamo.
I use ironPython 2.7 and loading the etree libraries.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET # Python 2.5
#INPUT
dataEnteringNode = IN
pfad=IN[0]
datei_name=IN[1]
sd_ifc_link=str(IN[2])
sd_liste=IN[3]
sd_pkt_liste=IN[4]
```

Until this point i am only getting lists from dynamo and trying to bring them into a loop to create a XML file. The strange thing is, that the code is working from time to time.. Sounds very weired but day before (without any changes it worked and i also have the XML-File) but a newer XML is not working.

I dont get any error of my script itself. Its telling me that the XML-creation is finished. When i try to open the XML-File i wont get the correct structure, cause the end wasnt compiled so far. Manually editting it and saving is working..

My questions are:

1. is there anything wrong with my way of loop to create a XML file
2. is there anything further i need to know about the etree in case of creating XML? Why is it working so "sporadically"?

One thing i need to say:
The correct XML i can open in the browser and i see the normal structure,
but when i try to open it in notepad++ for example, then its just 1 single line. Is there a limit of signs or something?

This is when the XML-creation is working, or if i just fix the broken part
[XML-File.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr3vT.png)

```
sd = ET.Element("SD_Fachmodell")
ET.SubElement(sd, "TGA", name="SD").text = sd_ifc_link
sd_ifc_name = ET.SubElement(sd,"SD-Elemente")
ET.SubElement(sd_ifc_name,"Anzahl").text= str(len(sd_liste))+ " Durchbrüche"

lauf = 0
for sd_i in sd_liste:
sd_id= ET.SubElement(sd_ifc_name, str(sd_i[0]))
sd_pkte=ET.SubElement(sd_id, "Lage")
ET.SubElement(sd_pkte, "XP").text = str(sd_pkt_liste[1][lauf])
ET.SubElement(sd_pkte, "YP").text = str(sd_pkt_liste[2][lauf])
ET.SubElement(sd_pkte, "ZP").text = str(sd_pkt_liste[3][lauf])
ET.SubElement(sd_pkte, "WKS").text = str(sd_pkt_liste[0][lauf])
sd_val = ET.SubElement(sd_id,"Parameter")
ET.SubElement(sd_val, "Form").text= str(sd_i[1])
ET.SubElement(sd_val, "Art").text= str(sd_i[2])
if (sd_i[3]!=""):
    ET.SubElement(sd_val, "Gewerk").text= str(sd_i[3])
ET.SubElement(sd_val, "Ebene").text= str(sd_i[4])
if (sd_i[5]!=""):
    ET.SubElement(sd_val, "Breite").text= str(sd_i[5])
if (sd_i[6]!=""):
    ET.SubElement(sd_val, "Höhe").text= str(sd_i[6])
ET.SubElement(sd_val, "Tiefe").text= str(sd_i[7])
if (sd_i[8]!=""):
    ET.SubElement(sd_val, "Durchmesser").text= str(sd_i[8])
ET.SubElement(sd_val, "Status_Neu").text= str(sd_i[11])
ET.SubElement(sd_val, "Status_Geändert").text= str(sd_i[9])
if (sd_i[10]!=""):
    ET.SubElement(sd_val, "TGA_Kommentar").text= str(sd_i[10])
lauf=lauf + 1

#Build_XML_Tree
tree = ET.ElementTree(sd)
tree.write(open(pfad + '\\'+ datei_name + '.xml', "w"), encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True, method='xml')
#OUTPUT
OUT = [pfad]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Instead,I suggest that you pick your first problem and post a  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to give us a good, focused problem to solve.